# Packing Floats into a long long

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I would like to pack 2 floats into an long long. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure it is possible ? 2 floats takes 2*4 bytes = 8 bytes, an uint32 contains no more than 4 bytes, am I wrong ?

Comment: I changed your title to reflect `long long` since that's what your body is now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly depends how portable you want it to be, in two senses: what platforms it works on at all, and what platforms it gives the same answer on. But something like this.

```
#include <stdint.h>

long long pack(float lo, float hi) {
    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    assert(sizeof(long long) == 8);
    assert(CHAR_BIT == 8);

    uint32_t target;
    memcpy(&target, &lo, sizeof(target));
    long long result = target;
    memcpy(&target, &hi, sizeof(target));
    result += ((long long)target) << 32;
    return result;
}
```

The "other" way to get the bits of a float as an integer in one write+read is with a so-called "union cast", but I prefer memcpy. You can also access the float one `unsigned char` at a time and build up the `long long` with 8-bit shifts.

Comment: How is this better than simply putting two floats in a struct?

Comment: @DigitalRoss: I don't know, but the question is how to pack two floats into a `long long`, not how to store two floats in a struct.

Comment: You could memcpy() directly into the result, if you cast &result to char* and add 4 to it for one of the calls.

Comment: @Sergey: I certainly don't mind if you do that. I considered it but I didn't want to think about endianness - my code gives the same output for the same input provided that `int` and `float` have the same endianness (regardless of which it is). I've seen middle-endian `long long`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.  A float is 32 bits wide, so only one float fits in a `uint32_t`.

To your edited question, depending on how [over]zealous your compiler is about strict aliasing optimizations, you may be able to do something like this.  Be sure to test however, because compilers love to break this sort of thing.  A safer implementation would probably use `memcpy`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

union converter { uint32_t i; float f; };

uint64_t pack(float a, float b) {
    union converter ca = { .f = a };
    union converter cb = { .f = b };
    return ((uint64_t)cb.i << 32) + ca.i;
}

void unpack(uint64_t packed, float *a, float *b) {
    union converter ca = { .i = packed };
    union converter cb = { .i = packed >> 32 };
    *a = ca.f;
    *b = cb.f;
}
```

Note: use `[u]int64_t`, not `long long`; there's no guarantee that `long long` is exactly 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your floats are represented using 32-bits, in general you will not be able to do this without losing data.

If you absolutely have to do this you may want to convert them each to a 16-bit float (aka "half")  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format

The wikipedia page includes a link (at the very bottom) which provides info on how to do the conversion in C.

Once you have the 'halves' you can then bit mask & shift them into your 32-bit integer.

**Update** , Now that question was changed to 'long long' instead of uint_32:

The memcpy solution has been mentioned, here is an example using a union:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union
{
    uint64_t llv;
    float fv[2];
} conv ;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    conv a;
    conv b;

    a.fv[0] = 1.0;
    a.fv[1] = -2.0;

    printf("%f %f\n",a.fv[0],a.fv[1]);
    b.llv = a.llv;
    printf("%f %f\n",b.fv[0],b.fv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Echoing stephen's comment, use uint64_t instead of long long.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    void *float1_bits = &float1;
    void *float2_bits = &float2;
    long long packed_floats = (*(long long*)float2_bits << 32) | (*(long long *)float1_bits);
```

Comment: This could break on hardware that has different requirements for float and long long alignment. It is generally only safe to cast to char*.

Comment: If it doesn't break for the reasons mentioned, it will most likely return zero -- you want `|`, not `&`.

Comment: @Stephen: Whoops! Fixed, to the extent it can be.

Answer (score 1):

The standard float and double are 4 and 8 bytes, so you can't directly pack two of them into one int<sub>32</sub> object as it is only 4 bytes.

However, you could define a 16-bit format with a limited precision and exponent range. (I didn't check to see if there already was a standard. There probably is but this is more fun.)

```
f e d c|b a 9 8|7 6 5 4|3 2 1 0  
S E E E|E E m m|m m m m|m m m m
```

My new format, called Ross-float, has a sign bit, 5 bits of exponent, and 10 bits of precision.

This format can represent integers exactly from -1023 to +1023, and it can represent real numbers in about the range of 10<sup>-4.8</sup>   to   10<sup>4.8</sup>.

***Update:***

Ok, now the question has changed to *long long*, so the whole problem becomes trivial. That's just as well, because 16 bits is not enough for a good floating point number.

Comment: There is a standard for 16 bit floats.  Please don't go inventing your own.  It is called `binary16` (or "half precision"), and is defined in the IEEE-754 (2008) standard as a so-called "storage format" (meaning it should only be used for data storage purposes, and computation should be performed in a wider type).

Comment: Well, I did say there was probably a standard, and given the constraints, it's perhaps not too surprising that I reinvented the same format. I should have accounted for hidden bit normalization in my range examples, though.